# CSS not working in certain areas of page?

Tags: css, html, hover, rollover

I am working on a page of my site with just plain old HTML and CSS (and a little bit of jquery using the innerfade.js script). I have my code aligned in divs, and have set up some CSS rollovers using the `background-image` and `hover` attributes. However, for some reason, they stop working in a certain area of the page - everywhere else, even on the same div, they work fine, just not in that one area.

Is there anything that may be causing this? If so, how could I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Problem was solved, it was a `position: absolute` on one of my divs that was throwing it off. Thanks again to Ben Baudart!

Comment: Can you post your site/css? Kind of hard to guess your issue with nothing to look at.

Comment: if you can post code, someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. I will update my post in just a second.

Comment: isn't your css dependant on a certain class, which no longer exists (element was deleted)? say `div.foo div.bar { color: red }` without the `div.foo` in html?

Comment: @PetrMarek I don't believe so, as it was working before I changed the map and positioning of elements around. Before, I had a Google map instead of just an image as a map, and I just changed the elements' position value to absolute instead of relative, so I don't believe that would have done anything.

Comment: Just a tip that might be causing an issue, you cannot put block elements (`<div>`) within inline tags (`<a>`). A good browser will just fail and not do what you want, unfortunately it only takes advice like this or experience to recognize when you've done something like that. If you want to get the same effect, make the outer tag `display: block` and use an inline tag (`<span>`) inside also with `display: block`. Example: `<a><span></span></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the absolute positioning of this div

```
<!-- BEGIN "TRIP PLANNER" BOX -->
            <div id="planTripContainer" style="margin-top: 57px; position: absolute;">
```

like this:

```
<!-- BEGIN "TRIP PLANNER" BOX -->
            <div id="planTripContainer" style="margin-top: 57px;">
```

It seems to solve the trick here: http://jsfiddle.net/66Swj/4/

But I have no idea of what it does to the rest of your code…

Comment: Alright, awesome, thanks. I didn't think a simple little position: absolute would do much, but apparently it did. :D It just threw off the alignment a bit, but I can just adjust margins. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! For your info, I used the very useful [WebDevelopper toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) to hover the area, and saw that the container seemed to be on top of the map! **Cheers**